# Using RequestScope without ServletModule

Tags: jersey, guice, requestscope

I was exploring `@RequestScoped` and was wondering if there's way to use it without installing `ServletModule`. I am using Guice 3.0 + Jersey 1.17 and probably don't want to use `GuiceContainer` & `GuiceServletContextListener`.

I want object creation(injections) per request depending on some user input in the Jersey request. Is it possible? What can be performance & security considerations of using `GuiceContainer` if I had to replace my existing `ServletContextListener` with that of Guice?

If there's a way of using `RequestScope` as per my needs, can you give me some references for the same?

Comment: It seems like the way to manually create a RequestScope is to use `ServletScopes.scopeRequest`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41237632/1631803

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to bind a custom `Scope` implementation to a predefined scoping annotation like `@RequestScoped`. It does mean that then you *cannot* use `ServletModule`, since you can't bind two different implementations to the same scoping annotation.

See the [documentation on Custom Scopes](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomScopes) for details. You will need to write code to determine what constitutes a "request" for purposes of scoping, and trigger entering and exiting the scope as necessary.

For example, in the normal Guice implementation, [`ServletScopes.RequestScope`](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/extensions/servlet/src/com/google/inject/servlet/ServletScopes.java#L65) uses a `ThreadLocal` [initialized in `GuiceFilter`](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/extensions/servlet/src/com/google/inject/servlet/GuiceFilter.java#L132) to keep track of what the current request is.